# Lower bounding the Bhattacharyya distance with the Chernoff distance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

Consider the Bhattacharyya distance

$$B = -\ln \sum_k \sqrt{p_k q_k},$$

where $p$ and $q$ are probability distributions, $\sum_k p_k = \sum_k q_k = 1$. I know that the Bhattacharyya distance is upper bounded by the Chernoff distance, i.e., $B \leq C$ with

$$C = \sup_{t\in[0,1]}\left\{-\ln\sum_k p_k^t q_k^{1-t}\right\}.$$

The equality occurs for symmetric distributions $p$ and $q$, in which case the supremum occurs at $t=1/2$.

By messing around, I found that $C$ also allows to lower bound the Bhattacharyya distance:

$$B \geq C/2.$$

A sketch of a proof is included below. Feel free to double check.

What I'd like to know is whether this inequality has a name and if I can have some reference for it. Maybe one of you knows. Or maybe it's just too trivial for that.

Comment: Note sure if it has a name, but fwiw the quantum analogue is (32) here: https://arxiv.org/abs/0708.4282

Comment: I believe you are right, though it is stated in a slightly different way, with the square instead of the 1/2. What's funny is that I think I ended up citing that paper but didn't notice it was in there.

Answer (score 1):

**Proof**: Consider the function $c(t) = -\ln\sum_k p_k^t q_k^{1-t}$. First note the $c(t)$ is a concave function of $t$ that is positive in $[0,1]$. Moreover, it vanishes at $t = 0$ and at $t=1$. Therefore, the supremum of $c(t)$ occurs at some $t^* \in [0,1]$. The value of $c(t)$ at $t^*$ is the Chernoff distance:

$$c(t^*) = C.$$

Similarly, the Bhattacharyya distance is the value of $c(t)$ at $t = 1/2$:

$$c(1/2) = B.$$

Wihtout loss of generality, focus on the case $t^* < 1/2$. The proof for $t^* > 1/2$ is similar. Consider the line that crosses $c(t)$ at the points $(1,0)$ and $(1/2,B)$. The equation of this line is $y(t) = 2B(1-t)$. Because $c(t)$ is concave and because $t^* < 1/2$, the supremum $c(t^*)$ must occur below this line:

$$c(t^*) \leq y(t^*) \Rightarrow C \leq 2B(1-t^*) \Rightarrow C \leq 2B$$

This proves the theorem.